# Unexpected bash function output

Tags: bash

I have written a 'to_upper' function using bash scripting:

```
to_upper() {

    local string=$1
    echo $string | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"
    return 0
}
```

However, the output of:

```
VAL=bla
echo $(to_upper bla)
echo $(to_upper $VAL)
```

is

```
BLA
1
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

**NOTE**: It seems my example does not reproduce my error. However, what I do have is this situation:

```
DEVICE_STATUS=$(get_device_status)
echo $DEVICE_STATUS $(to_upper $DEVICE_STATUS)
```

The output is then:

```
active 1
```

My example seems to not reproduce the problem, but it's there on my script.

**NOTE 2**: I fixed the problem; it was some grep output on the `get_device_status` function which ended up on `$DEVICE_STATUS`.

Comment: Not reproducible in my bash 4.1.5 too.

Comment: neither in my bash, GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

Comment: You don't need to call the function in sub-process. Instead of "echo $(to_upper bla)" you can go "to_upper bla".

Comment: Please tell us what shell and version are you using (and perhaps also platform).

Comment: To all: please see my edit (I'm on ubuntu 12.04, bash 4.2.24)

Comment: Add some delimiters in the last output, like `echo "[$DEVICE_STATUS] [$(to_upper $DEVICE_STATUS)]"`, to see more clearly what are the values. So far it looks strange.

Comment: Please post your fix as an answer to your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem: in the `get_device_status` function there was a `grep` command which was outputting junk to `$DEVICE_STATUS`. Redirecting the `grep` output to `/dev/null` solved the problem.

I am not quite sure in this case why `$DEVICE_STATUS` picked up the correct value on the `echo` but not on the call to `to_upper`.